# How to add a time sequence column, based on groups

Tags: python, pandas

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L7YQxyN9d-TKmEzHJUBMN3SXJxSnNgRJx3xISCE_v50/edit?usp=sharing)

Above is a link to an example of a CSV file I am modifying using python, I need to add a time column that increases by 1 if the date from the previous row matches.

If the date Changes the time would start back over at 8:00:00

additionally if the 'PL Seq' changes from G* to H* the time would also start back over at 8.

I think I have the logic down, just having a hard time writing it.

add a column to the df 'Time'
set the first 'Time' value to 8:00:00

read each row in the df

If date value = date value of previous row and pl seq value first character = first character set time value to time +1

else set time value to time

*Just a note I already have the code to change the format of the order #'s and the Dates of the Goal state

### Current

```
MODELCHASS,Prod Date,PL Seq
M742-021167,20200917,G0005
M359-020535,20200917,G0010
M742-022095,20200917,G0015
M220-001083,20200918,G0400
M742-022390,20200918,G0405
M907-004747,20200918,H0090
M934-005904,20200918,H0095
```

### Expected

```
MODELCHASS,Prod Date,PL Seq,Time
M742 021167,2020-09-17T,G0005,8:00:00
M359 020535,2020-09-17T,G0010,8:00:01
M742 022095,2020-09-17T,G0015,8:00:02
M220 001083,2020-09-18T,G0400,8:00:00
M742 022390,2020-09-18T,G0405,8:00:01
M907 004747,2020-09-18T,H0090,8:00:00
M934 005904,2020-09-18T,H0095,8:00:01
```

@Trenton Can we modify this If H orders have the same date as G orders
for example

### Current Edit in Line 6

```
MODELCHASS,Prod Date,PL Seq
M742-021167,20200917,G0005
M359-020535,20200917,G0010
M742-022095,20200917,G0015
M220-001083,20200918,G0400
M742-022390,20200918,G0405
M907-004747,20200917,H0090
M934-005904,20200917,H0095
```

### Expected Edit

```
MODELCHASS,Prod Date,PL Seq,Time
M742 021167,2020-09-17T,G0005,8:00:00
M359 020535,2020-09-17T,G0010,8:00:01
M742 022095,2020-09-17T,G0015,8:00:02
M220 001083,2020-09-18T,G0400,8:00:00
M742 022390,2020-09-18T,G0405,8:00:01
M907 004747,2020-09-17T,H0090,8:00:00
M934 005904,2020-09-17T,H0095,8:00:01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert the `'Prod Date'` column to a datetime
- Sort the dataframe by `'Prod Date'` and `'PL Seq'` so `'df'` will be in the same order as `time_seq` for joining.
- The main part of the answer is to create a `DateRange` list with the `.groupby` and `.apply`
- `.groupby` the `Prod Date` and the first element of `'PL Seq'`

  - `df.groupby(['Prod Date', df['PL Seq'].str[0]])`
- `.apply(lambda x: (pd.date_range(start=x.values[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8), periods=len(x), freq='s')).time)`

  - For each group, use the first value in x as `start`: `x.values[0]`

    - To this date, add an 8 hour Timedelta, to get `08:00:00`
  - The number of `periods` is `len[x]`
  - the `freq` is `'s'`, for seconds.
  - This creates a `DateRange`, from which the time is extracted with `.time`
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd

# setup test dataframe
data = {'MODELCHASS': ['M742-021167', 'M359-020535', 'M742-022095', 'M220-001083', 'M742-022390', 'M907-004747', 'M934-005904'],
        'Prod Date': [20200917, 20200917, 20200917, 20200918, 20200918, 20200918, 20200918],
        'PL Seq': ['G0005', 'G0010', 'G0015', 'G0400', 'G0405', 'H0090', 'H0095']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert Prod Date to a datetime column
df['Prod Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Prod Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

# sort the dataframe by values so the order will correspond to the groupby order
df = df.sort_values(['Prod Date', 'PL Seq']).reset_index(drop=True)

# groupby Prod Date and the first character of PL Seq
# create a DateRange sequence for each group
# reshape the dataframe
time_seq = (df.groupby(['Prod Date', df['PL Seq'].str[0]])['Prod Date']
            .apply(lambda x: (pd.date_range(start=x.values[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8), periods=len(x), freq='s')).time)
            .reset_index(name='time_seq')
            .explode('time_seq', ignore_index=True))

# join the time_seq column to df
df_new = df.join(time_seq.time_seq)

# display(df_new)
    MODELCHASS  Prod Date PL Seq  time_seq
0  M742-021167 2020-09-17  G0005  08:00:00
1  M359-020535 2020-09-17  G0010  08:00:01
2  M742-022095 2020-09-17  G0015  08:00:02
3  M220-001083 2020-09-18  G0400  08:00:00
4  M742-022390 2020-09-18  G0405  08:00:01
5  M907-004747 2020-09-18  H0090  08:00:00
6  M934-005904 2020-09-18  H0095  08:00:01
```

Comment: Thanks Trenton, I updated the question as well, but it looks like everything is working perfect